# Generating Unique String in PHP for Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I generate a unique Key and insert it into my `mysql` database?

This is what I currently use:

```
echo uniqid(time(), true);
```

Can you tell me wether it is a unique key or not?

Comment: Why not let MySQL handle it using an auto incrementing number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following to get unique id with 32 chars

```
md5(uniqid(time(), true))
```

or you can use sha1 like with 40 chars

```
sha1(uniqid(time(), true))
```

Comment: `md5` does not always create a unique hash. It has [collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities).

Comment: For my need this answer is perfect :)

Comment: Note that the resulting string can be guessed, see the *Warning* in PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php So you should not use in a URL or an auth system since an attacker can brute-force this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AUTOINCREMENT` on your **id** field in the database.

It will never get duplicate since it increments the highest existing id present.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this method throw unique id.

```
function generate_uid(){
    return md5(mktime()."-".rand()."-".rand());
}

$uniqueString  = generate_uid();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a php function `uniqid()`, more reference [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get unique id with add your prefix also:

```
echo md5(uniqid('myprefix_', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a unique string

```
    function gen_random_string($length=16)
        {
            $chars ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";//length:36
            $final_rand='';
            for($i=0;$i<$length; $i++)
            {
                $final_rand .= $chars[ ran

d(0,strlen($chars)-1)];

        }
        return $final_rand;
    }

    echo gen_random_string()."\n"; //generates a string
    echo gen_random_string(8)."\n"; //generates a string with length 8
```